# Distribute nodes evenly across a circumference

Tags: c++, user-interface, cocos2d-x, trigonometry

What I'm trying to do is a "carousel" control where is the nodes are evenly distributed from the origin and evenly distributed from each other on the arc.

My error is in the way how a new node is added to the circumference (node is added on top of another node or they are overlapped, **not evenly distributed**)

[picture example of not evenly distributed nodes](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8655042/ui%20control%20error.png)

And here is the function to add a (node) PotSprite (blue cycle) to the (circumference) RingSprite (purple ring):

```
void RingSprite::addPot () {
    auto pot = PotSprite::create( "Pot.png" );
    this->addChild( pot );

    float radius = this->radius() * 0.88f;
    auto children = this->getChildren();
    float angleStep = 360.0f / children.size();

    Vec2 pos;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < children.size(); ++i ) {
        pos = this->calcPointOnCircumference( radius, angleStep * i );
        children.at( i )->setPosition( pos );
    } 
}

Point calcPointOnCircumference (float radius, float angle) {
    return Point (cosf( angle ) * radius + this->getAnchorPointInPoints().x, 
                  sinf( angle ) * radius + this->getAnchorPointInPoints().y);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing what `calcPointOnCircumference` is doing, I can almost promise that your `angleStep` should be in radians instead of degrees.

Comment: Could it be that 360 degrees should be expressed in radians, i.e. 2 * PI?

Comment: @Cyber, Drux you are right, it uses radians instead of degrees. Big thanks! :)